# Extract elements from numpy array, that are not in list of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to do something similar to what was asked here [NumPy array, change the values that are NOT in a list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940895/numpy-array-change-the-values-that-are-not-in-a-list-of-indices), but not quite the same.

Consider a `numpy` array:

```
> a = np.array([0.2, 5.6, 88, 12, 1.3, 6, 8.9])
```

I know I can access its elements via a list of indexes, like:

```
> indxs = [1, 2, 5] 
> a[indxs]
array([  5.6,  88. ,   6. ])
```

But I also need to access those elements which are *not* in the `indxs` list. Naively, this is:

```
> a[not in indxs]
> array([0.2, 12, 1.3, 8.9])
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
In [170]: a = np.array([0.2, 5.6, 88, 12, 1.3, 6, 8.9])
In [171]: idx=[1,2,5]
In [172]: a[idx]
Out[172]: array([  5.6,  88. ,   6. ])
In [173]: np.delete(a,idx)
Out[173]: array([  0.2,  12. ,   1.3,   8.9])
```

`delete` is more general than you really need, using different strategies depending on the inputs.  I think in this case it uses the boolean mask approach (timings should be similar).

```
In [175]: mask=np.ones_like(a, bool)
In [176]: mask
Out[176]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [177]: mask[idx]=False
In [178]: mask
Out[178]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [179]: a[mask]
Out[179]: array([  0.2,  12. ,   1.3,   8.9])
```

Answer (score 9):

One way is to use a boolean mask and just invert the indices to be false:

```
mask = np.ones(a.size, dtype=bool)
mask[indxs] = False
a[mask]
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create the mask of the ones from `indxs` present and then inverting it and indexing the input array with it for the desired output -

```
a[~np.in1d(np.arange(a.size),indxs)]
```