# Rearrange NumPy Array Efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a simple 1D NumPy array:

```
x = np.random.rand(1000)
```

And I retrieve the sorted indices:

```
idx = np.argsort(x)
```

However, I need to move a list of indices to the front of `idx`. So, let's say `indices = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` need to always be the first 5 and then the rest will follow from `idx` (minus the indices found in `indices`)

A naive way to accomplish this would be:

```
indices = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
out = np.empty(idx.shape[0], dtype=int64)
out[:indices.shape[0]] = indices

n = indices.shape[0]
for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
    if idx[i] not in indices:
        out[n] = idx[i] 
        n += 1
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently and, possibly, in-place?

Comment: You prabably mean `idx = np.argsort(x)`?

Comment: `np.argmin(x)` is one index, not a list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894594/extract-elements-from-numpy-array-that-are-not-in-list-of-indexes this can help

Comment: Oops! Yes, it should’ve been argsort. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One way would be with `np.isin` masking -

```
mask = np.isin(idx, indices, invert=True)
out = np.r_[indices, idx[mask]]
```

**Approach #2 :** Skipping the first `argsort`

Another with making those given indices minimum, thus forcing them to be at the start with `argsorting`. We don't need `idx` for this method as we are argsort-ing in our solution anyway -

```
def argsort_constrained(x, indices):
    xc = x.copy()
    xc[indices] = x.min()-np.arange(len(indices),0,-1)
    return xc.argsort()
```

**Benchmarking - Closer look**

Let's study how does this entire thing of skipping the computation of starting `argsort` `idx` helps us with the second approach.

We will start off with the given sample :

```
In [206]: x = np.random.rand(1000)

In [207]: indices = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

In [208]: %timeit argsort_constrained(x, indices)
38.6 µs ± 1.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [209]: idx = np.argsort(x)

In [211]: %timeit np.argsort(x)
27.7 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [212]: %timeit in1d_masking(x, idx, indices)
     ...: %timeit isin_masking(x, idx, indices)
44.4 µs ± 421 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
50.7 µs ± 303 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note that if you use `np.concatenate` in place of `np.r_` with these small datasets, you could do better.

So, `argsort_constrained` has a total runtime cost of around `38.6 µs`, whereas the other two with masking have around `27.7 µs` on top of their individual timing numbers.

Let's scale up everything by `10x` and do the same experiments :

```
In [213]: x = np.random.rand(10000)

In [214]: indices = np.sort(np.random.choice(len(x), 50, replace=False))

In [215]: %timeit argsort_constrained(x, indices)
740 µs ± 3.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [216]: idx = np.argsort(x)

In [217]: %timeit np.argsort(x)
731 µs ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [218]: %timeit in1d_masking(x, idx, indices)
     ...: %timeit isin_masking(x, idx, indices)
1.07 ms ± 47.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.02 ms ± 4.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Again, the individual runtime costs with masking ones are higher than with `argsort_constrained`. And this trend should continue as we scale up further.

Comment: I apologize in advance but I made a mistake. My input array is actually 2D and the output should actually be the sorted values from the array `x` and not the indices. I've update my question with the details but let me know if it is preferable to post a brand new separate question. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: Yes probably post a new question, and leave this one as is, since both answers solve the question as was originally posed @slaw

Comment: @yatu Thank you. Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936423/rearrange-2d-numpy-array-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

You can build a mask with where the `indices` are contained in `idx` with `np.in1d`, and just concatenate both indexing arrays:

```
m = np.in1d(idx, indices)
out = np.r_[indices, idx[~m]]
```