# converting from R in python

Tags: python, r

I am converting R code to python. I know the alternative of calling R from python exists, however, I need it converted to python line by line.

I have a line in the R code which says 
`reps[-a] <- .Machine$integer.max` 
where reps is a vector and a is another vector containing some indices, eg
a = [1, 2, 4]

I wanted to know how to implement this line in python. 
From what I understand, it should assign the max value to all the elements in the array where the index does not equal 1,2 or 4.

Thank you.

Comment: If it is a column, then you may need to subset `df1.column.isin([1,2,4])`

Comment: Hi akrun, Both reps and a are 1-D vectors

Comment: this is not which.max which is numpy.argmax

Comment: May be you need `for i in a:
    reps[~i] = np.argmax`

Comment: If you want a max number `sys.maxsize`

Comment: When I run the code below, I expect to get an array that is [1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0] <br> Instead I get the following output. <br>`a = [1, 3, 4, 6, 79, 10, 56] <br>
b = [0, 1, 2] <br>
for i in b: <br>
    a[~i] = 0 <br>
    
a <br> [1, 3, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0] ` <br> Want to know why 6 is also being printed

Comment: if you change it 10000000, how do you get 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best translation of R's atomic vector/matrix/array is Python's numpy N-D [`array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and `.Machine$integer.max` would translate to the max `int32` value of numpy dtype.

However, numpy arrays do not have an easy index locator and hence a longer route is necessary as shown by [@mglison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941004/1422451) using a boolean mask:

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6, 79, 10, 56])    
b = np.array([0, 1, 2])

mask = mask = np.full(a.shape, False)
mask[b] = True
a[~mask] = np.iinfo(np.int32).max

a
# array([         1,          3,          4, 2147483647, 2147483647,
#    2147483647, 2147483647])
```

Alternatively, Python's pandas [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) is an extension of the numpy 1-D array but requires alignment of indexes:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 3, 4, 6, 79, 10, 56])
b = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])

a[~a.index.isin(b)] = np.iinfo(np.int32).max

# 0             1
# 1             3
# 2             4
# 3    2147483647
# 4    2147483647
# 5    2147483647
# 6    2147483647
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: for the numpy version, why is `a[3] != np.iinfo(np.int32).max` after  the masking?

Comment: @Parfait Hi, I would like for the 6 in a to also be masked just like it is in the series example. Is there anyway to achieve that without using pandas. Thanks

Comment: Whoops! Read too fast. Numpy arrays do not have a `not in` list property. So you will need to use a boolean mask. See edit.

Comment: I like the 2013 reference :D!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a boolean mask using `np.ones` with `dtype=bool`.  Then simply mask `reps` after you have set `mask[a] =False`:

```
import numpy as np

reps = np.random.randint(0,10, 20)
a = np.array([1,2,4])

mask = np.ones(reps.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[a] = False

reps[mask] = np.iinfo(np.int32).max
```

which returns:

```
array([2147483647,          4,          4, 2147483647,          0,
       2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647,
       2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647,
       2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647])
```

or a one-liner variation of @akrun's answer:

```
reps[list(set(range(len(reps))) - set(a))] = np.iinfo(np.int32).max
```

Comment: Hi, the one liner gives an error saying, list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: Weird,  I just re-ran it over here and it works fine.  how about using [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html): `reps[np.r_[list(set(range(len(reps))) - set(a))] ]= np.iinfo(np.int32).max`

Answer (score 1):

An option is

```py
for i in set(range(len(a))) - set(b):
    a[i] = 1e5

a
#[1, 3, 4, 100000.0, 100000.0, 100000.0, 100000.0]
```

#### data

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 6, 79, 10, 56]
b = [0, 1, 2]
```