# How to get the values of NumPy array that are NOT in my list of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find values in an np.array corresponding to an index and then those that are not in the index. In R, I would do

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> ind = c(1,4)
> x[ind]
[1] 1 4
> x[-ind]
[1] 2 3 5
```

In Python, I can index and get the values in the index in the following manner

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
ind = [0,3]
x[ind]
```

However, in Python how can I get the values NOT in my index as I show in the R code using `x[-ind]`?

I found the SO post below and have replicated this, but is this indeed the "right" or best approach?
[NumPy array, change the values that are NOT in a list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940895/numpy-array-change-the-values-that-are-not-in-a-list-of-indices)

Comment: What do you mean by "right or best"? Best in terms of what? That answer works, so what else exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most intuitive way would be with [np.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)

```
np.delete(x, ind)
```

As it gives you back the remainig elements

```
array([2, 3, 5])
```

Comment: I like that - but it is inplace.

Comment: @modesitt from the docs: A copy of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. Note that delete does not occur in-place. If axis is None, out is a flattened array.

Comment: Nice - my bad. Don't know why i thought was in place

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a solution quite as pretty as `R`s, but how about

```
x[~np.isin(np.arange(len(x)), ind)]
```